# AngularFire 2.0.1 $createUserWithEmailAndPassword auth/invalid-api-key

Tags: angularfire, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a Firebase user from AngularFire 2.0.1 (Firebase 3.0.5) using:

`$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`

The api returns an error:

```
{"code":"auth/invalid-api-key",
  "message":"Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly."}
```

The config for the app looks like this:

```
{apiKey: "my_verified_key", 
 authDomain: "my_verified_project_id.firebaseapp.com", 
 databaseURL: "https://my_verified_project_id.firebaseio.com/"}
```

where my_verified_key is the database secret found at

`https://console.firebase.google.com/project/my_app/settings/database`

my_verified_project_id is the ProjectId found at

`https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/settings/project?project=my_verified_project_id&consoleReturnUrl=https:%2F%2Fconsole.firebase.google.com%2Fproject%2Fmy_verified_project_id%2Fsettings%2Fgeneral%2F`

In the network log I see that the error comes from a POST to

`https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=my_verified_key`

I have checked that identity toolkit api is enabled for my app.

I've tried disabling/enabling email/password authentication in the Firebase control panel as suggested elsewhere.

I have tried to create the user from the node library but it seems that most of the auth functionality is not implemented there.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are getting the correct API Key. Go to the firebase console page:
https://firebase.corp.google.com/project//authentication/users
Click WEB SETUP on the top right corner:
The snippet provided will contain the auto generated api key for you to user.

Comment: I think that maybe an internal Google link. I found the key you are talking about at https://console.firebase.google.com/project/my_project/authentication/users.

Comment: My error was to assume that the apiKey for Firebase 3 was the same apiKey that I used for Firebase 2. It's not. You need to use the key from the link above.

Comment: Why the hell the api key given in https://console.firebase.google.com/project/my_app/settings/database and the one in WEB SETUP are different ?